# Dynamic Firebase Connection to the same app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can My App Connect to different Firebase Project Without register the app in the project (the package name and SHA-1) ? and still able to use firestore, storage and google sign in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. But I believe the app should be connected via SHA-1 as you said to one project, and then you can add other projects without registration.

Implementation guide for those who might be interested in it. This article is also a good resource to show how to connect, database, authentication and storage. [Multiple Firebase Projects One App](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html)
Initialize the secondary project, the one not connected to the Firebase project in the class that extends Application but any activity should work.

```
FirebaseOptions issuetracker = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId("project id")
            .setApplicationId("")
            .setApiKey("")
            .setDatabaseUrl("")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, issuetracker, "issues");
```

Then where you want to interact with it

```
FirebaseApp secondary = FirebaseApp.getInstance("issues");
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(secondary).getReference();
```

"issues" is any name you give for the secondary project. Can be anything.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but that's not the question, am asking about possibility not the implementation

Comment: Implementation implies possibility

Comment: Whthout register the app in the secondary project?

Comment: Yes, no need to register secondary project

Comment: But what about a primary project, the same concept is applied?

Comment: Primary project needs to be registered to connect to Cloud Console for Google Sign In, and to connect to Firebase. What I posted as implementation above is then done automatically for the primary project (the one you placed the SHA1 in). Then for any other project, no need to connect via SHA1 and all that.